# Escape single quotes in string variable in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, double-quotes

We've decided to move away from setting strict quote escaping to false for our code, but before we do we're going through and fixing all the JSP strict quote escaping issues.

Normally we have a line with quotes inside of quotes and the simplest fix is to just make the outer quotes single instead of double. I came across this portion of a line today though:

```
url="<%= "javascript:deleteFromHistory('" + personStatus.getId() + "');" %>"
```

Sticking single quotes on the outside doesn't work since there are single quotes inside of the double quotes which are inside of the double quotes.

So I tried to stick the inner quoted content into a string variable and use that, it seems to compile just fine, but since I'm not sure where this page shows up in our product and my limited knowledge in how to test this stuff, I'm not sure if this solution actually works, or if the single quotes within the string variable need to be escaped as well.

```
String link = "javascript:deleteFromHistory('" + personStatus.getId() + "');";
....
....
<td....><ia:btn.... url ="<%=link%>"....
```

Will this solution work, and if not, what would be an appropriate way to handle this?

I don't want to just assume I did it right because it compiled.

Comment: Relax your solution works fine..i've tested it and the single quotes too dont need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also able to find another example of this on a page I could test with. The solution provided in the question does work for triple quote issues in JSPs.